# getComputedStyle returns a CSSStyleDeclaration but all properties are empty on access

Tags: css, properties, getcomputedstyle

I have a simple div that uses a css class which in turn has a `color` and `background-color` property set.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.classList.add("my-css-class");
container.appendChild(div);

//This prints out a CSSStyleDeclaration object. This is a large object to which I see `color` and `backgroundColor`
console.log(getComputedStyle(div));

//this gives me an empty string
console.log(getComputedStyle(div).color);

//this gives me an empty string
console.log(getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue("color"));
```

Why am I unable to access the properties of the CSSStyleDeclaration?  I know it is there from my first log. I can see `color: "rgb(82, 194, 145)"`

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a JSFiddle or CodePen?

Comment: Thank you @swider . I sat down today with JSFiddle for the first time, and I found the solution as a result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ultimately the problem with `getComputedStyle` is that it appears that the element in question must be a part of the DOMTree in order for any style to be available.

Notice in my case, I was adding the div to the parent container, however, the parent container at the point of instantiation is not yet added to the DOMTree.

My failure to use `JSON.stringify()` to print the object meant that values were appearing later but at the time of access, were blank.

So basically, I changed my `container.appendChild` to `document.body.appendChild` temporarily to compute the style I need straight away, and then remove it and destroy it leaving me just the colors I needed.