# How can I test styles coming from sass with jest and react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, sass, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to test styles of a component from sass, but only inline styles are loaded in the dom

my test case:

```
   describe('Danger', () => {
      const dangerLabel = <DangerLabel>TESTE</DangerLabel>;
      it('deve ter class -danger', () => {
        const { container } = render(dangerLabel);
        expect(container.firstChild).toHaveClass('-danger');
      });
      it('deve ter a cor vermelho', () => {
        const { container } = render(dangerLabel);
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(container.firstElementChild);
        expect(style.backgroundColor).toBe('#e74c3c');
      });
    });
```

jest-config

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  transform: {
    '\\.(js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/public/'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/config/jest/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '.+\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
};
```

component export:

```
 import LabelContainer from './label_container';
    import Label from './DefaultLabel';
    import DangerLabel from './DangerLabel';
    import PrimaryLabel from './PrimaryLabel';
    import WarningLabel from './WarningLabel';
    import SuccessLabel from './SuccessLabel';
    import InfoLabel from './InfoLabel';
    import '../assets/styles/label.scss';
    
    export default Label;
    export {
      LabelContainer,
      PrimaryLabel,
      DangerLabel,
      WarningLabel,
      SuccessLabel,
      InfoLabel,
    };
```

exec:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "#e74c3c"
    Received: ""

      30 |       const { container } = render(dangerLabel);
      31 |       const style = window.getComputedStyle(container.firstElementChild);
    > 32 |       expect(style.backgroundColor).toBe('#e74c3c');
         |                                     ^
      33 |     });
      34 |   });
      35 |
```

I have tried some packages like jest-transform-css and jest-transform-scss but with no success, it is possible to do that test?

As requested
DangerLabel Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultLabel from './DefaultLabel';

const DangerLabel = props => (
  <DefaultLabel {...props} className="-danger" />
);

export default DangerLabel;
```

DefaultLabel
[image]

With toHaveStyle:

```
 it('deve ter a cor vermelho', () => {
      const { container } = render(dangerLabel);
      expect(container.firstElementChild).toHaveStyle(`
        background-color: rgb(231, 76, 60)};
      `);
    });
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Could you please also include the code for the `DangerLabel` in the description?

Comment: sure @ypahalajani, done

Comment: The code in the image is not the same code as the one you’ve added

Answer (score 2):

You had been missing the `visible` prop when rendering `DangerLabel` in the test file which is why it was not rendering and failing test #1.

```
const dangerLabel = <DangerLabel visible>TESTE</DangerLabel>;
```

The next error that you'll face is the empty string for all CSS properties in the `style` object that you get from the `window.getComputedStyle` (in test #2). There is a [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35432063/2925949) to it.

So, I went ahead with an alternate implementation of asserting the background colour CSS property using [toHaveStyle](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavestyle) from the jest-dom lib. itself.

I had to use an npm module [hex-rgb](https://github.com/sindresorhus/hex-rgb) for converting the hex color to a rgba value.

See the solution working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-react-testing-library-x7yno?file=/src/App.test.js:186-247). To view the test results in codesandbox, read [this](https://codesandbox.io/docs/tests)

Bonus: Using `style` object did not work but there is a declarative way of accessing the CSS properties from the return value of `getComputedStyle` - `const backgroundColor = style. getPropertyValue ('background-color)`.

Comment: Thank you for the codesandbox example, about the visible sorry, it was configured as true in default props. I have tried as you did with toHaveStyle, and put color as rgb still not working, i'll put the extra changes on description

Comment: Did you check the test file in the codesandbox link? The test cases are passing there. Check the test file with the syntax you are using. Also, paste the error and the code using toHaveStyle that you are facing and using respectively.

Comment: I put the last code and result in the description, I saw the codesandbox but I didn't understand. Any hexadecimal color I put in, returned success, and the css file doesn't contain any label background style, also my case is using scss maybe there is some difference

Comment: Ok, can you replicate your behaviour in a codesandbox and send a link here so that I can help you better?

Comment: Got it! It is because of the difference in the version of `@testing-library/jest-dom` npm package that we are using. See it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64998343/2925949)

Comment: Kindly share your exact version of `@testing-library/jest-dom` so that I can try reproducing the issue.

Comment: "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0", "jest": "^27.0.5",

Comment: Can you share the exact module version from the lock file?

Comment: @testing-library/jest-dom = 5.14.1, @testing-library/react = 12.0.0 I'll try to add my code to codesandbox

Comment: Ok, apparently the string `rgba(321, 76, 60)` works (adding `a` (denoting alpha in rgba))

Comment: True, the case passes with rgba but it doesn't matter the color, it always passes, I put in the codesandbox one more case to assert for white and I add the red in the css, both pass. https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-react-testing-library-forked-lspik?file=/src/App.test.js

Comment: Yes, even I checked it later - it is weirder 